# On ttest why t-stat is greater than one?

Tags: statistics, excel, implementation

I have my data in two culomns as below:

[image]

On excel did this ttest and this is my result:

[image]

I can not Understand why **Hypothesized Mean Difference =0** but **tStat = -1.6367...**?

I mean my NULL/Zero Hypothesized has been accepted and t-Stat must be close to zero, am I wrong?